# Wayward Thumbnail generation in dynamic PHP script

Tags: php

This script snippet checks to see if a file exists in a directory and the builds a thumbnail.  For some reason before the _1.jpg thumbnail an empty thumbnails is created with just a .jpg?  Where is this happening, I can track it down?

Here is a tinyurl of the issue to see...best to test in IE as firefox automatically removes it:  http://tinyurl.com/c6o2yts

```
<?
                                    $image = "<br>";
                                    $ListingRid = $row['ListingRid'];                                   
                                    $img_cnt = 1;
                                    $image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/$ListingRid_1.jpg rel=enlargeimage::mouseover rev=loadarea><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/$ListingRid_1.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
                                    for ($c=1;$c<10;$c++) {
                                        $c_ext = $c;
                                        if (file_exists("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg"))
                                            $image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg rel=enlargeimage::mouseover rev=loadarea><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_{$c_ext}.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
                                        else
                                            $c=12;

                                        $img_cnt++;
                                        if ($img_cnt == 3) {
                                            $image .= "<br>";
                                            $img_cnt = 0;
                                        }

                                    }

                                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/$ListingRid_1.jpg rel=enlargeimage::mouseover rev=loadarea><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/$ListingRid_1.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
```

And more specifically here:

```
$ListingRid_1.jpg
```

PHP allows underscores and integers in variable names.  So while you want it to find `$ListingRid . "_1"`, PHP interprets the variable's name as `$ListingRid_1`,  which does not exist.

You could use brackets, so that it becomes

```
$image .= "<a href=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_1.jpg rel=enlargeimage::mouseover rev=loadarea><img src=/feeds/fmfl/rets_images/{$ListingRid}_1.jpg alt='' width='100' height='75' border='0' /></a>&nbsp;";
```

Also:
As an aside, a better way to exit a `for` loop early is to use `break`.